# how to make android recycler views adapter accept different data types?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, greendao

i have a lot of recycler views, they all use the same adapter, i used to update them with arraylists of objects that id make as i went like this

***ADAPTER***

```
private List<CardWriter> cardMakerList;


public CardAdapter(List<CardWriter> cardMakerList){
    this.cardMakerList = cardMakerList;
   // this.mContext = context;
}
```

***ACTIVITY***

```
 public List<CardWriter> cardMakerList = new ArrayList<>();
 public CardAdapter cardAdapter;
 recyclerView.setAdapter(cardAdapter);
 CardWriter cardWriter = new 
 CardWriter(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.happy),"HAPPY","happy ");
 cardMakerList.add(cardWriter);
```

**THE PROBLEM**

Ive now switched to using databases for each recycler view (using greenDao see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37973207/greendao-how-to-create-tables-with-the-same-entity-but-different-titles) question) so my adapter now uses the below code (addNewCard refers to the generated java class made by greendao)

```
 public List<addNewCard> leaseList = new ArrayList<>();
```

but now to get my second database(2) its the exact same properties but greendao makes a different file so i should use this in my adapter

```
 public List<addSimpleCard> leaseList = new ArrayList<>();
```

but this would mean a new adapter for every database and im going to need a lot of them. All the databases im making are just lots of the same object with different properties (an image and 2 strings) but each database needs to be managed individually.
my last question (in the link above) asks how i can make all the same databases with a different title which i think would also solve my problem.

**WHAT IVE TRIED**
I've tried just creating an static reference to the array list and passing it the new one eg:

```
public static CardAdapterDB cardAdapterDB;

cardAdapterDB = new CardAdapterDB(leaseList);
```

this works but trying to change it for a new database

```
cardAdapterDB = new CardAdapterDB(simpleleaseList);
```

gives me an error

> `CardAdapterDB(java.util.List<greendao.addNewCard>)` in `CardAdapterDB` cannot be applied to `(java.util.List<greendao.addSimpleCard>)`

`addSimpleCard` is the name of my other java file generated by greendao so this makes perfect sense but how can i get around this without creating loads of new adapters and switching them all the time?

since asking this ive tried multiple ways to get this to work but have yet to find something suitable

Comment: 1) Make `addSimpleCard` and `addNewCard` follow Java naming conventions 2) Make them implement a common interface or abstract `Card` class and make a List of that

Comment: Okay what should I be changing in this case for Java naming convention, tautology is confusing. The project I'm using to create my databases does have a way of doing this I believe  entityA.implementsInterface(); but I've no idea how to use it or what it does so I guess I've got some reading to do thanks for your reply @cricket_007

Comment: If you want to add this as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: I mean, it's just a general solution. I don't really know how to apply it to GreenDAO